# Problem with Showing dynamically an image in Angular

Tags: angular, list, image, ng-init

So I have a list of doctors and I want to display for each doctor in the list the corresponding image. The doctors have an ID so I tried to make the path for the image on ng-init but it still does not work. Can someone help me out? Here's the code.My images are stored in the assets/img folder and the corresponding image for every doctor matches the id of the doctor (Example: Doctor 1 with the id 1 has the image "1.jpg" etc. Also, is there any easier way to do this? Thank you!

```
<li *ngFor="let doctor of doctors">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div ng-init="ImgPath ='assets/img/' + doctor.doctorId +'.jpg"></div>
          <img ng-src="{{ImgPath}" alt="" />
        </div>
```

(...)

Comment: what version of angular are you using here?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up AngularJS with angular here. `*ngFor` is a special directive in angular (2.x - 13.x), where as `ng-init` and `ng-src` are directives used in AngularJS (1.x). While it sounds similar, they are very different frameworks in its implementations and do not share any code-base.

Comment: Oh alright. And do you know a fix for this issue? How am I supposed to link them?

Comment: I am using Angular 13

Answer (score 1):

Supereasy! You can use only this:

```
<img src="assets/img/{{doctor.doctorId}}.jpg"/>
```

or you can bind it on .ts file

html:

```
<img [src]="urlImage(doctor)"/>
```

ts:

```
urlImage(doctor) {
  return `assets/img/${doctor.doctorId}.jpg`;
}
```

**ng-init** and **ng-src** are directives of AngularJS! **Don't use it in Angular >2**